# Media query ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to add a media query in react to check the size of the screen before applying width.

This is my code :

```
const myConfig = {
  nodeHighlightBehavior: true,
  node: {
    color: "lightgreen",
    size: 120,
    highlightStrokeColor: "blue",
    labelProperty: "name"
  },
  link: {
    highlightColor: "lightblue"
  },
  @media (max-width: 960px){
  width: window.innerWidth * 0.9
};
```

> Error: Line 76:  Parsing error: Stage 2 decorators disallow object literal property decorators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a higher order component (HOC) to solve this issue. Using something like the [react-media library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) (you would need to install the react-media library) one could have the following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Media from 'react-media';

class OriginalComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const myConfig = {
      nodeHighlightBehavior: true,
      node: {
        color: "lightgreen",
        size: 120,
        highlightStrokeColor: "blue",
        labelProperty: "name"
      },
      link: {
        highlightColor: "lightblue"
      }
    }
    if (this.props.small) {
      myConfig.width = window.innerWidth * 0.9
    }
    return (
      <div style={myConfig} />
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Media query="(max-width: 960px)">
          {matches =>
            <OriginalComponent small={matches} />
          }
        </Media>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But having a HOC might be a little overkill for your usage.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are a CSS property and you are using it as a JavaScript attribute.

You either need to write the media query on CSS and apply it to a component, perhaps a global wrapper component.

Or you use JavaScript to get the width of the page and then set it on your myConfig, for this you can use DOM methods like offsetWidth

```
const documentWidth = document.body.offsetWidth

...
},
width: documentWidth < 960 ? window.innerWidth * 0.9 : window.innerWidth * 0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import that from file.css because `CSS in JS` don't support it, then use `className`.

Else, you can use `react-responsive`

Comment: Lol that's not even close to `css in js`